# Document DataType in HSQLDB support

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, hsqldb

On Java side, Hibernate, I have Document as a datatype. I am mocking via in memory db(**HSQLDB**) for JUnit testing. What would be the suitable datatype for storing this Document datatype.

EDIT: What is the best data type to represent an XML document in HSQLDB in the process of creating a table. On Oracle db I used  SYS.XMLTYPE. On Java Hibernate I used Document data type to Insert the stream. Once inserted I dont need it anymore, I keep updating the XMl every time a change is made.

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either LONGVARCHAR or CLOB types.

Comment: CLOB Worked!! thank you...do u happen to know the default value for CLOB. currently I am referring to [link](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#datatypes-section).

Comment: Can CLOB (having xml document) can be fetched as string. I want to keep xml document/xml data in hsqldb column and send it to a webservice as string.... anyway possible?

Comment: Yes, CLOB can be fetched as String if it is not very very large. For huge CLOBs you can fetch it as a stream.